# Specify attribute's minimum length

Tags: linux, group-policy, ldap, openldap

I'm implementing a new infrastructure which will include a kind of Microsoft's GPO using ldap, dns, dhcp and pam.

I'm creating a new schema to store the information I need, and I have a `groupPolicyId` attributeType which describe a 32 characters identifiers.

For this I did the following:

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.39259.2.1.1 NAME 'groupPoliciId'
    DESC 'Group Policy Identifier'
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32}
    )
```

Using the `SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32}`, I specify that I want an UTF-8 encoded string which is *at most* 32 characters.

I now need to set a minimum length, googled for hours and didn't find anything which may helps.
Any Idea?
Thanks.